# calling python script with context menu

Tags: python-2.7, registrykey

Im trying to add a python script to the context menu in windows10.

Im fine with the python but Im struggling to get the registry correct

I've searched around and followed suggestions from other posts but have had no success. im getting this error:
"This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action"

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Sequence to movie]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Sequence to movie\command]
@="C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ffmpeg_test.py" "%1"
```

What Im hoping is to right click on an image sequence, select my script command and the image file/sequence is processed by python and ffmpeg

Comment: oh, i have kinda put tis here too:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316907/right-click-command-pass-argument-to-python-script